# Объединение большого числа файлов в Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, агрегация

В компании решили реорганизовать систему хранения и обработки данных.

**Суть вопроса**: существует огромное количество машин, которые генерируют каждый день несколько файлов небольшого размера. Но в целом количество файлов за сутки превышает 100000. Структура файлов почти одинакова. И руководство хочет, чтобы эти файлы были объединены в один или базу данных и проанализированы на кластере Hadoop. Поскольку данные структурированные, логичнее всего анализ делать на Hive.

Как такие файлы можно объединить? Загружать все в hdfs и агрегировать там? Слишком долго - Hadoop на это не рассчитан.

Кто что посоветует? Желательно готовые решения.

Comment: Сильно долго будет само копирование или анализ? Для анализа можно теоретически посмотреть в сторону Spark поверх Hive к примеру

Comment: В том то и дело что анализ долгий. Именно поэтому ищем какое то решение. А так можно было бы устроить загрузку файлов к примеру через Flume и анализировать их.

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону _Filebeat_, чтобы сливать содержимое файлов по мере поступления.

Answer (score 0):

Неудивительно, что все медленно работает, Hadoop плохо подходит для обработки кучи мелких файлов - это создает нагрузку не только на Namenode,но и порождает кучу mapper'ов на каждый мелкий файл, и это давно известная проблема.

Решение одно: объединять маленькие файлы в большие. Для решения этой проблемы уже существует несколько инструментов, например -  [filecrash](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/filecrush), вообще, данная проблема легко гуглится: hadoop small file problem.

P.S. Опять же,эта проблема актуальна,если вы используете фреймворк MapReduce,потому что Hive умеет работать не только поверх MapReduce,но и Tez,Spark итп.